# Attempting to set title for views in xcode iOS project

Tags: ios, xcode

What do I need to do to be able to set the title of each main view in my iOS project. Below is what I've got so far and what I'm attempting to do...

Created Files That I'm attempting to get to work together.

- PageTitleView.h
- PageTitleView.m
- PageBaseViewController.h
- PageBaseViewController.m
- HomeViewController.h
- HomeViewController.m
- ActivityFeedViewController.h
- ActivityFeedViewController.m

Essentially setup the PageTitleView.h * .m along with PageBaseViewController.h & .m so that I can then make a call into the HomeViewController&ActivityFeedViewController and set the title of the current view.

Here is my code from those files

---

**PageTitleView.h**

```
#import "ContainerView.h"
#import "BaseLabel.h"

@interface PageTitleView : ContainerView
@property (nonatomic, strong) BaseLabel* label;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* title;

@end
```

---

**PageTitleView.m**

```
#import "PageTitleView.h"

@implementation PageTitleView

@synthesize label;



- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, 35)];
    label = [[BaseLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(18, 10, frame.size.width , 25)];
    label.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0];
    label.textColor = (UIColor *) COLOR_DARK_BLUE;
    label.text =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"text"];


    self.backgroundColor = (UIColor *)COLOR_WHITE;

    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.05;
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(.25, .25);
    self.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 5;

    self.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.layer.bounds].CGPath;


    self.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;

    self.layer.borderWidth = 0.25;
    self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;


    [self addSubview:label];

    return self;
}



@end
```

---

**PageBaseViewController.h**

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Settings.h"
#import "CustomButton.h"
#import "PageTitleView.h"

@interface PageBaseViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CustomButton *backButton;


@end
```

---

**PageBaseViewController.m**

```
#import "PageBaseViewController.h"

@interface PageBaseViewController ()

@end

@implementation PageBaseViewController
synthesize scrollView;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    // GRADIENT
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = self.view.bounds;
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       (id)BACKGROUND_GRADIENT_COLOR_1.CGColor,
                       (id)BACKGROUND_GRADIENT_COLOR_2.CGColor,
                       (id)BACKGROUND_GRADIENT_COLOR_3.CGColor,  nil];
    gradient.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                          (id)[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0],
                          (id)[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4],
                          (id)[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil];
    [self.view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];



    float height = self.view.frame.size.height - TITLEBAR_HEIGHT - self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height;
    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, TITLEBAR_HEIGHT, self.view.frame.size.width, height)];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];


    PageTitleView *pageTitle = [[PageTitleView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(105, -10, 100 , 35)];
    [self.view addSubview:pageTitle];



    /* This button is currently added to the view and will show in the TITLEBAR_HEIGHT. 
     These will be used throughout the entire project, we will be working next to have 
     correct buttons turn on and off for each view.*/

    CustomButton *buttonLeft = [[CustomButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 60, 25) andText:@"Left"];
    [buttonLeft addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonLeft:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [buttonLeft setBackgroundColor:BUTTON_COLOR_1];
    [self.view addSubview:buttonLeft];

    // Remove this button from homeview and have a logo show up.
    CustomButton *buttonRight = [[CustomButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(235, 5, 80, 25) andText:@"Right"];
    [buttonRight addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonRight:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [buttonRight setBackgroundColor:BUTTON_COLOR_1];
    [self.view addSubview:buttonRight];



}


- (void)buttonLeft:(UIButton *)buttonLeft {
    NSLog(@"Ping");
}

- (void)buttonRight:(UIButton *)buttonRight {
    NSLog(@"Ping");
}

@end
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this with the following steps.

1. Imported the PageTitleView.h into the PageBaseViewController.h
2. In the PageBaseViewController.h declared the following property

   @property (nonatomic, strong) PageTitleView *pageTitle;
3. Then in the PageBaseViewController adjusted the import of PageTitleView

   From:
   PageTitleView *pageTitle = [[PageTitleView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(105, -10, 100 , 35)];

   To:
   pageTitle = [[PageTitleView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(105, -10, 100 , 35)];
4. Then in one of my views for example HomeViewController I added the following code.

   [self.pageTitle setTitle:@"Home"];
5. Now I'll add the following code to my other views and fill it in with the appropriate name.

   [self.pageTitle setTitle:@""];